# SonarQube server can not be reached by Jenkins using Docker

Tags: jenkins, docker, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I have added a SonarQube Scanner analysis step to my Jenkins build, but the step fails:

```
[Test_gitlab] $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/http_INTERNAL_DOCKER_IP_ADDRESS_9000/bin/sonar-scanner -e -Dsonar.host.url=SERVER_IP_ADDRESS:9000 ******** -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Test_gitlab
INFO: Option -e/--errors is no longer supported and will be ignored
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/http_INTERNAL_DOCKER_IP_ADDRESS_9000/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.8
INFO: Java 1.8.0_102 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 amd64
INFO: User cache: /var/jenkins_home/.sonar/cache
ERROR: SonarQube server [SERVER_IP_ADDRESS:9000] can not be reached
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 0.214s
INFO: Final Memory: 4M/209M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:84)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:218)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:156)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:72)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from server
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.downloadFiles(Jars.java:93)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.download(Jars.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:39)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:75)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected url: SERVER_IP_ADDRESS:9000/batch_bootstrap/index
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Request$Builder.url(Request.java:141)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:109)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:98)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.downloadFiles(Jars.java:78)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

My SonarQube Scanner is declared in Jenkins Global Tool Configuration. The name used is "http://SERVER_IP_ADDRESS:9000". This is the same address as the server base URL that I have set within SonarQube General Settings.

I'm using Docker: Jenkins is in a Docker container, and so does SonarQube.

The "unexpected url" mentioned in the stacktrace `SERVER_IP_ADDRESS:9000/batch_bootstrap/index` can be opened in a browser, 
which displays `sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.1.jar|SOME_LETTERS_AND_NUMBERS`. 
So why can't Jenkins reach the server?

I've also tried with Docker internal IP address, that can be found with:

```
docker inspect SONARQUBE_CONTAINER_ID | grep IP
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find place where you define the "unexpected url" mentioned in the stacktrace (parameter `sonar.host.url` of SonarQube Scanner) and prefix it with `http://`.

URLs must start with a scheme - see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax). Browser simply adds `http://` by default.

Comment: Indeed, we can see at the first line of the console that the wrong host url is set:
 `sonar-scanner -e -Dsonar.host.url=SERVER_IP_ADDRESS:9000`
 I tried to modify the default values in sonar-scanner.properties, but the wrong host url does'nt seem to come from there.
I will try to find which script is calling sonar-scanner with this argument.

Comment: I finally found the place where the "unexpected url" was set:
Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> SonarQube servers ->  SonarQube installations -> Server URL
The `http://` was missing there. I thought I had verified every Jenkins page, but not this one.
Thank you for your help.